# Uploading Multi part content through HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, php, android, httpurlconnection, ioexception

I want to upload a pdf file with few parameters to my server from my android app. I have spent almost 2 days in searching answer but always a new problem arises when I try a solution. At present there is no error in this code but still the file is not getting uploaded nor the database is getting changed. Please help to rectify my code.
My code at present is like this:

1) Upload Function:

```
public void upload_file(String file_dir, String user_id,String path){

        try {
            String hyphen="--";
        String boundary="Bound";
        String newline="\r\n";

        URL url = new URL("http://117.**.**.**.**:****/upload.php");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "mutlipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

        DataOutputStream oStream = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        //First Send Parameters so that database can be changed
        oStream.writeBytes(hyphen+boundary+newline);
        oStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain\n");
        oStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"u_id\"" + "\r\n");
        oStream.writeBytes(user_id+newline);
        //oStream.flush();

        oStream.writeBytes(hyphen+boundary+newline);
        oStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain\n");
        oStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"path\"" + "\r\n");
        oStream.writeBytes(path+newline);
        //oStream.flush();

        oStream.writeBytes(hyphen+boundary+newline);
        oStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/pdf\n");
        oStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: post-data;name=\"file\";" +
                "filename=\"s1.pdf\"" + "\r\n");

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(file_dir);
        int filesize=file.available();
        Log.d("size", "" + filesize);
        int buffersize = 1024*1024;
        byte buff[] = new byte[buffersize];

        int byteRead = file.read(buff, 0, buffersize);  

        while (byteRead > 0) {

          oStream.write(buff, 0, byteRead);
          byteRead = file.read(buff, 0, buffersize);   
         }

        oStream.writeBytes(newline);

        InputStream iStream = conn.getInputStream();
        char arry[] = new char[1000];
        Reader in = new InputStreamReader(iStream, "UTF-8");
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        while(true){
            int rsz = in.read(arry, 0, 1000);
            if (rsz < 0)
                break;
            response.append(arry,0, rsz);
        }
        Log.d("String",response.toString());                                  

         Log.d("Response","Res.."+conn.getResponseCode());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

2) My php file at my server: upload.php

```
<?php

    require_once 'db_connect.php';

    $obj = new DB_Connect();
    $conn = $obj->connect();

    if(!$conn){
        echo mysql_error();
    }

    var_dump($_POST);
    var_dump($_REQUEST);
    print_r($_FILES);

    $file_path = "Docs/";
    $u_id=$_POST["u_id"];
    $path=$_POST["path"];
    $file = $path."/".basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

    $qrry = mysql_query("insert into file values('$file','$u_id',now(),'pdf')");
    if(!$qrry)
    echo "error";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

When I checked the echos from my php file I found that neither the parameter nor the file is received by it...So please help me to know what is mistake in this code.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83666/discussion-on-question-by-gaurav-jindal-uploading-multi-part-content-through-htt).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the minimal [HTTPS Upload Library](https://github.com/Addicticks/httpsupload). Despite the name it works with HTTP as well. It is only about 20K and is really just a wrapper around `HttpURLConnection` so I find it very suitable for Android. It saves you from having to understand multipart upload, encoding and what not. It's available also from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.addicticks.oss%22%20AND%20a%3A%22httpsupload%22).

Your example would look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    HttpsFileUploaderConfig config = 
         new HttpsFileUploaderConfig(new URL("http://myhost/upload.php"));

    Map<String,String> extraFields = new HashMap<>();
    extraFields.put("u_id", "foo");
    extraFields.put("path", "bar");

    HttpsFileUploaderResult result = HttpsFileUploader.upload(
            config,
            Collections.singletonList(new UploadItemFile(uFile)),  // your file
            extraFields, // your fields
            null);

    if (result.isError()) {
        throw new IOException("Error uploading to " + config.getURL() + ", " + result.getResponseTextNoHtml());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The multipart message produced by your program is wrong: Missing the main body, missing the boundary declaration... This is the format you should produce instead:

```
Message-ID: <000000001>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_0_842618406.1437326651362"

------=_Part_0_842618406.1437326651362
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=myfile.pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.pdf

<...binary data...>
------=_Part_0_842618406.1437326651362--
```

I truly recommend to you not to produce MIME messages from the scratch; instead you'll save yourself trouble by using the Java Mail API, for example with this program:

```
public void createMultipartMessage(File[] files, OutputStream out)
    throws MessagingException,
    IOException
{
    Session session=Session.getDefaultInstance(System.getProperties());
    MimeMessage mime=new MimeMessage(session);
    Multipart multipart=new MimeMultipart();
    BodyPart part;

    // Send form data (as for http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2):
    part=new MimeBodyPart();
    part.setDisposition("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"<name>\"");
    part.setContent("<value>");        
    multipart.addBodyPart(part);

    // Send binary files:
    for (File file : files)
    {
        part=new MimeBodyPart();
        part.setFileName(file.getName());
        DataHandler dh=new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(file));
        part.setDataHandler(dh);
        multipart.addBodyPart(part);
    }
    mime.setContent(multipart);
    mime.writeTo(out);
}
```

You must include in your runtime the mail-1.4.1.jar and activation-1.1.1.jar libraries.

Comment: I can also send parameters using the mail API by creating a new MimeBodyPart() before the for loop...right?

Comment: Right. I've included a block in the previous example.